# Accessing data from an array irrespective of scope (GLOBAL simulation) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables

I have some secure user information which is inserted as at the top of my template (I am using CMS Made Simple, pages are built from various component parts, so code is split between locations).

I want to access the array of user attributes at multiple points in the site, the solution that sprung to mind was to, at point of arrival, store the attributes in MySQL and then call on them directly from that where ever I am in the site.

**My simple question:** is this a good way to do things? Or is there an accepted way to get arrays globally accessible (I hear that actually using the global array is frowned on these days?)

Comment: You could use $_SESSION. $_GLOBAL is also fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables you are accessing are user specific, this is exactly the sort of thing that the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable was created for. Don't forget to make call to `session_start()` at the beginning of each script that accesses it, or none of your previously set values will be there (and any values you set will not be saved).

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions if its user specific data

Comment: oh - d'oh, of course, that's probably more straight forward. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding globals is a good idea when developing an OOP application, but this does not mean strictly $GLOBALS.

It means that you should avoid designs that rely on global scope.

So don't avoid the $GLOBALS array, avoid needing it.. If you're 'simulating' it, that's probably actually worse.

The simple answer: just create a function that returns the data, or a class with a method that does.